# Xamarin Essential Share in iOS 13

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ios13, xamarin.essentials

I wanted to implement share feature in my app with xamarin forms '4.2.0.709249' and xamarin essential 1.3.1
Everything works fine except Reminder feature in iOS 13.0. It does not get my title or URI that i am sending through my share api. And also the 'Add' and 'Cancel' button on the top are not showing up though they are already there. So here is my code:

```cs
await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest
{
    Uri = "https://www.google.com",
    Title ="Share the link"
});
```

[iOS 13 reminder with xamarin Essential share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzHk7.png)

Comment: `Title` (and `Subject`) is not used on iOS, this is noted in the "Platform Differences" section of the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=ios#platform-differences

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing the expected behavior on iOS.

On iOS, `Xamarin.Essentials.Share` does not support `Subject` and `Title`, as noted in the [Platform Differences section](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=ios&WT.mc_id=social-stackoverflow-bramin#platform-differences) of the docs.

[image]